# Does Craft have built-in queue handling for outbound mail?

Tags: emails

Does Craft have built-in queue handling for outbound mail? For example if Settings -> Email -> Protocol is set to "SMTP" and the mail server is temporarily down when an email is to be delivered, the email will then be delivered later when the mail server is online again?

I guess the answer is no, and that it's better to use sendmail if it's important messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess the answer is no

Correct... Craft is just the middle-man between creating the email and using whatever selected service is used to send it.

Answer (score 1):

We are currently using Sendmail for a site, and messages were being blocked until we got their host to whitelist things.

So If it's an important message, I would use something like [PostMark](https://postmarkapp.com/), where deliverability is more reliable, plus you can also track whether messages were sent or not.  Not to mention their support is great!